# Assembly - Understanding SEH

Tags: assembly, x86, seh

I'm trying to understand how  exception handlers work on windows executables and I  came across the following :

```
 push ExceptionHandler
 mov eax, dword ptr fs:[00000000h]
 push eax
 mov dword ptr fs:[0], esp
```

Now I know that this is basically adding a new EH to the current thread's execption-handler list (which AFAIR is a linked list), my question is: aren't we missing something here? Isn't this overwriting the previous linked-list with the remaining EHs? How exactly can I properly add a new EH to exception-handler list?

Comment: fs:[0] only stores a pointer to the head of the linked-list.  The PUSH preserves it before the MOV overwrites it.  The nodes in the linked list thus have two fields, a pointer to the exception handler and a pointer to the previous node.  This style is outmoded btw, it is vulnerable to malware overwriting a node with a buffer overflow.  Replaced by SAFESEH.